# Ruby - Add multiple sheet with customized name in CSV

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I want to create a CSV file with multiple sheet(sheet1,sheet2 ..) also I should name the sheet in CSV file.

```
require 'csv'
csv_string  = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["Name", "age", "address"]
      csv << ["foo", "bar", "foo-bar"]
end
```

I am able to create only one sheet, How do I create multiple sheet.?

Kindly help

Comment: What do you mean "sheet"? Like in Excel? A CSV file isn't a spreadsheet, it's just columns of data separated by commas in rows separated by newlines. There are no "sheets." Perhaps if you could tell us what problem you're trying to solve we could help you find a solution that doesn't involve sheets.

Comment: Perhaps you should grab a CSV file and open it in a text editor to see its structure. It's just a text file, no sheets.

Comment: You mean open and write to multiple CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you create a CSV you're creating a "Comma Separated Value" file. You're going to need to use a rubygem:

https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet